# Where can I find a list of differences between Rails 2.x and Rails 4.x?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'd like to see a list of the major differences between Rails 2.x and Rails 4.x. I've searched through lots of blogs and sites, all in vain.

Comment: I'm not sure how your search would be in vain, unless you were looking for something specific and couldn't find it. But ultimately, those versions are *considerably* different, and listing all major differences would be a bit of a task (without knowing specifically what differences you're interested in knowing).

Comment: The site [railsdiff.org](http://railsdiff.org/) will allow you to compare specific versions of Rails. For a list of all Rails versions, with comments and links to version notes see [Ruby on Rails Release History](http://railsapps.github.io/rails-release-history.html).

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the [upgrading Ruby on Rails page](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/upgrading%5fruby%5fon%5frails.html) is helpful. It lists all the steps to take to upgrade your application.

Also interesting because it lists all the differences:

- [Rails 3.0 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3%5f0%5frelease%5fnotes.html)
- [Rails 3.1 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3%5f1%5frelease%5fnotes.html)
- [Rails 3.2 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/3%5f2%5frelease%5fnotes.html)
- [Rails 4.0 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4%5f0%5frelease%5fnotes.html)